# Periodic signal alarm

Tags: python, signals, alarm

I would like a my Python script to receive a periodic alarm say every 5 seconds. I have tried the following code, but it only receive the alarm once then hangs.

```
import os
import signal
import time

def handler(signum, stack):
    print 'Alarm: ', time.ctime()

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(5)
```

Comment: You might find the `sched` module in the standard library of interest.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

Answer (score 2):

Nothing hangs, nothing receives the alarm once. Your program is already dead when the alarm bell rings the first time. Try so:

```
import signal
import time

def handler(signum, stack):
    print 'Alarm: ', time.ctime()

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(5)
time.sleep(10)
print "interrupted"
```

When you want it in a loop, just wrap it in a loop:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
for i in range(1000):
    signal.alarm(5)
    time.sleep(10)
    print "interrupted #%d" % i
```

You can also do infinite loop. But catch `KeyboardInterrupt` in this case to avoid nasty exceptions like

```
Alarm:  Sat Mar 19 08:28:06 2016
interrupted #2
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "alaam.py", line 10, in <module>
    time.sleep(10)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Note: `signal.SIGALRM` only works on Unix : https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html

Answer (score 0):

Because alarm is set once only. If you need periodic 
Try this:

```
def handler(signum, stack):
   print 'Alarm: ', time.ctime()
   signal.alarm(5)
```